# Create a second form that references the same List (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: forms, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want to create a second form that references to a created list, which already has some data in it.

So the situation is that there's a list with jobs (offers and demands). With one form that exists users can insert a offer, but now I need a second one to put the demands in it.

I made some research, but the only thing I found was that I needed external software. The problem is, that the company's security doesn't allow "custom software" so i can't use it and have to do everything with SharePoint.

How can I create another form without any programs like SharePoint Designer, just with SharePoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a content type for each type of data (ie.offers and demands). Assign both content types to the list. This will allow you to have an offer form and a demand form within the same list.